# A version of Wordle that accepts Hollywood movies

Tags: knowledge, movies, wordle

*I was playing a version of Wordle that accepts only 5 letter Hollywood movie titles.*

---

*This is how I fared.*

[image]

---

***Which WB movie did I enter at last?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming all grey letters are *not* in the movie title, the title you are searching must contain only letters among the remaining letters in the alphabet.  The possible letters are BGJQSUVYZ.  And the S is mandatory.

Looking at https://bestforpuzzles.com/lists/films/5.html and eliminating all titles not starting with one of these letters, then removing all titles containing one of AEIO, ony a couple of titles remain.  Only one fits the allowed letters.

The only remaining title is ...

> [Bugsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugsy)

Comment: I thought of this movie too, but thought maybe there's more to it.. But I think this is it since WB could stand for rot13(Jneera Ornggl)

Comment: I had only one title, so I didn't bother checking who produced it...  But you are probably right.